# Hash with arrays - get array element

Tags: ruby

I get hash that contains user role, controller name and list of the controller actions  this role can access to.

```
access = {
    'admin' => [ 'users'    => ['edit','delete'],
                 'messages' => ['show','update']
               ],
     'user' => [ 'index'    => ['index','sign-out'],
                 'messages' => ['show','index']
               ]
}
```

How can i check what `access['admin']['users']['edit']` exists?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
access['admin']['users'].include? 'edit'
```

However, this may be a problem: you're using `... => ['users'=>['edit','delete'],...]`
This will create an array with a hash inside. Example:

```
{'a'=>'b'} #=> {"a"=>"b"}
['a'=>'b'] #=> [{"a"=>"b"}]
```

So consider using this:

```
access = {
    'admin' => { 'users'    => ['edit','delete'],
                 'messages' => ['show','update']
               },
     'user' => { 'index'    => ['index','sign-out'],
                 'messages' => ['show','index']
               }
}
```

Comment: @jtbandes thank you for reply, it's exact what i need) But `access['admin']['users'].contains? 'edit'`. says _no method exists_. I replace it with `access['admin']['users'].grep(/edit/).size >0` Maybe exists more elegant way?

Comment: @Vladimir Tsukanov: Glad I could help! If this answered your question, you can click the checkmark on the left, to mark it as answered. Thanks :)

Comment: @jtbandes I edited my previous comment. Maybe you know the answer

Comment: @Valdimir: Use `include?` instead of `contains?` and don't forget to add the missing comma between the `'admin'` and `'user'` hashes inside `access`.

Comment: Ah my mistake, the method is indeed called `include?` and not `contains?`.